# Google Cloud Storage Upload file from HTML using POST. Signature issues

Tags: google-app-engine

I am able to upload files anonymously to my google cloud storage bucket but have been unable to get the upload to work from a HTML page using a policy and a signature.

I have spent quite a lot of time reading several posts:

I have also tried to follow the Google Documentation for HTML POST described in their docs..can't post the link as I only have 1 reputation point...

My Policy Document is a simple JSON form very similar to the example in the google documents.

{"expiration": "2020-06-16T11:11:11Z",

"conditions": [

["starts-with", "$key", "" ],

{"acl": "bucket-owner-read" },

{"bucket": "XXXXXXXXX"},

{"success_action_redirect": "redirect url here...I had to remove it due to my reputation..." },

["eq", "$Content-Type", "application/pdf" ],

["content-length-range", 0, 1000000]

]

}

The XX's simply are redactions.

And, I am using the following HTML:

The Policy and signature strings have been truncated for display convenience.

```html
<form action="http://storage.googleapis.com/flashbidz_uploads/"
                              method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="text" name="key" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="XXXXX">
                            <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="application/pdf">
                            <input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="XXXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com">
                            <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-read">
                            <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="https://flashbidz.appspot.com/#/sellerhome">
                            <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcm...XQ0KfQ==">
                            <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="5P5lFuZ...nkTlyY=">

                            <input name="file" type="file">
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
                        </form>
```

When I run this I receive the message:
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.

The process I am following is to create a base64 representation of my policy from this site [here](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/Default.aspx) and then using this site [here](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator) to create the SHA-256 signature string (using the Base64 representation in the HTML) and signing it with the private_key_id of my service account key.

I have also used the email form of the key to sign and the client ID associated with the service account.

I have no idea where I am going wrong and do not have any idea how to debug this.  Any help would be very appreciated and I do understand that there are a lot of posts already on this subject.  I have read them (may not have understood them) all.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to authenticate first which will add the token in your browser session, later on you do not need to pass token explicitly. (see [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#how-it-looks-in-javascript) and [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#get-access-keys-for-your-application))

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html).

Comment: Thanks @varunpant, I am already using OAuth successfully in several applications.  I will take a look through the links you provided to see if there are any more clues.  I simply want to upload from a HTML Page using the B64 policy and a signature.  I will post back later today after I have had time to really take a solid look at your suggestions.  Thanks!